# Graphics2D DrawImage not representing image size

Tags: java, swing, graphics, 2d, paint

I am currently working on a project to make Connect 4 and I'm running into some problems with the coordinate system for it. I have an 800x600px png image which shows the 'board' and it is made up of an 8x6 grid with each location being a 100x100px square...at least that's how it is in GIMP2 and in the filesystem. However when I use Graphics2D's drawImage() method to paint the image onto a 800x600 JFrame it sticks off the bottom. Do I need to account for the JFrame's borders and stuff in this system, or am I missing something else?

Thanks!

P.S. Here is the JPanel class that does the drawing.

```
public class GameBoard extends JPanel { 
public GameBoard() {
}

public void paint(Graphics g) {
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

    //Write messages
    if (!(GameManager.getInstance().getMessage() == null)) {
        g2d.drawString(GameManager.getInstance().getMessage(), 400, 25);
    }


    //Draw board graphic        
    ImageIcon bg = new ImageIcon("res/board.png");
    g2d.drawImage(bg.getImage(), 0, 0, 800, 600, this);

    //Draw counters


    for (int columns = 0; columns < 8; columns++) {
        for (int rows = 0; rows < 6; rows++) {
            if (!(GameManager.getInstance().getState(columns, rows) == null)) {
                Counter cTemp = GameManager.getInstance().getState(columns, rows);
                g2d.drawImage(cTemp.getImage(), cTemp.getX(), cTemp.getY(), 100, 100, this);
            }                   
        }
    }       
}
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Override `paintComponent` instead of `paint` and call `super.paintComponent(g)`

   ```
   @Override
   protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
       super.paintComponent(g);
       ...
   }
   ```
2. Override `getPreferredSize()` for your `JPanel`

   ```
   @Override
   public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
       return new Dimension(800, 600);
   }
   ```
3. **Don't** create your image inside the `paintComponent` method. Do it in the constructor.

   ```
   public class GameBoard extends JPanel { 
       ImageIcon img;
       public GameBoard() {
           img = new ImageIcon(...);
       }
   ```
4. `pack()` your frame, **don't** `setSize()`, and the preferred size of the `JPanel` will be respected (by your override `getPreferredSize()`).
5. You can just use `getWidth()` and `getHeight()` after override `getPreferredSize()`

   ```
   drawImage(bg.getImage(), 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), this);
   ```

Work on all these things, if it doesn't help, post a runnable example we can test out.